# Django Attribute Error Type Object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

The idea is to have tasks and to add one or more tags to each task. The task models reference to the tag class is `tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)` and works fine in the admin interface. Now when I call my upload form the error

```
AttributeError at /upload/
type object 'Tag' has no attribute 'all'
```

shows up. Here is the upload form

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    title= forms.CharField(label='Tasktitle', max_length=255)
    data= forms.FileField(label='Data')
    tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Tag)
```

Considering I call the form in the views.py here is the function I am using:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newTask = Task(titel=request.POST['title'], tags=request.POST['tags'], data=request.FILES['data'])
            newTask.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('success/')
    else:
        form = UploadForm()
    return render(request, 'upload/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

I tied to adjust the different parameters, but I can't figure out where the call for an 'all' attribute comes from or why it is needed. If you need more information or clarification just add a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` accepts a queryset but your passing in a model

Try

`tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Tag.objects.all())`